# Adding a value to all elements in an array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, element

I have a query to get an array from a database.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `Time_D` from `Schedule` where `Stop` = 1 ");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {                         
echo $row['Time_D'] . "<br>";
}
```

This array ($row) contains a lot of times, if I'm not mistaken.

I now want to add for example 10 minutes to all the elements in the array.
How do I do that?

Comment: What type is 'Time_D' ? Timestamp, int, ...?

Comment: Why every answer is about mysql `UPDATE`? I dont see that in the question? He wants to add to all the elements in the **array**

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of response! 'Time_D' type = time. And it is true I want to put the array back in a database, even though it was not in the question :). I should have asked that instead, my bad. I do not want to just update the values though, I want them in a new table/column/added below in the same column so I can show them via a new query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, figured it out myself after all.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `Time_D` from `Schedule` where `Stop` = 1 ");

//get database result
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {                         
$rows[] = $row['Time_D']; //store all the times in one array
}
print_r ($rows);

echo "<br>";
$time_difference=600;
$i=0;

while (($i) < (count($rows)) ) {
$rows[$i] = ( strtotime($rows[$i]) ) + ($time_difference); //with timestamps, because, well, php and times...
$rows[$i] = date('H:i:s', ($rows[$i]) ); // back from timestamp to time
$i = $i +1;
}
print_r($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update like this

```
$row['Time_D'] = time() + 600;
```

or just 10 seconds

```
$row['Time_D'] += 600;
```

Then push it back to the database

```
mysql_query('update table_name set Time_D = '{$row['Time_D']}' where id = '{$row['id']}'
```

OR something to that end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the mysql query itself by using [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

```
"SELECT DATE_ADD(`Time_D`,INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AS 'Time_D' FROM `Schedule` WHERE `Stop` = 1 "
```

You can have a parameter like this in your `php` script:

```
$minutes_to_add = 10;

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DATE_ADD(`Time_D`,INTERVAL ".$minutes_to_add." MINUTE) AS 'Time_D' FROM `Schedule` WHERE `Stop` = 1 ");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
{                         
    echo $row['Time_D'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I must say the code looks beautifully simple, but unfortunately when I put it in my php file it doesn't output anything. when I try the query directly in phpmyadmin, it outputs the column 'Time_D' but as values only 'null' instead of the times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just noticed an error in phpmyadmin: "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

Comment: @PHPirate im guessing that the 'Time_D' is not of type "DATETIME". Maybe it is just type "TEXT" ? If it is not "DATETIME" then you must parse the whatever text you get, make the appropriate transormation to time ( strtotime http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php may help) and then add 10 minutes

Comment: I figured it out already. And 'Time_D' is not of type "DATETIME", but of "TIME". I don't think there's much wrong with that? I'd rather have stored it as timestamp, but this way it's more readable so I can be sure what's in my database. And yes, strtotime did help actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in SQL only:

```
"UPDATE `Schedule` SET `Time_D` VALUES = DATE_ADD(`Schedule`.`Time_D`,INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) where `Stop` = 1"
```

Comment: That seems to be an update query, but I don't want to update the values, I want to add 10 minutes to the existing times and make a new array and a new set of values in the database below or aside the existing values.

Answer (score 0):

You might be mistaken. `$row` does not contain a lot of times. As long as there are still records available, `$row` is assigned the next row of the query result as an array. If you want to alter all the times, save them to a new array. In your while-loop (don't forget to declare `$rows`):

```
$rows[] = $row['Time_D'];
```

`$rows` now stores all the times. You can then (after the while-loop) iterate over `$rows` and alter the data.

```
$rows = array_map(function($time) {
    return $time + (60 * 10); // Given $time is a timestamp
}, $rows);
```

If you don't want to save the times (i.e. directly output them in the while-loop), save the overhead of `array_map` and do it directly in the while-loop:

```
echo $row['Time_D'] + 60*10;
```

Depending on your exact situation you might want to use a key-value (i.e. id-to-time) storage for the times - otherwise you won't be able to refer them back to the "schedule" you are using.

*If you only want to update the database records see Axel's answer.*

Comment: You're absolutely right there in your first paragraph! Thanks a lot for that! I used     print_r($rows); to debug, and it now indeed shows all the times in the array. Now, when I print $rows after your function, I get as result "Array ( [0] => 608 [1] => 609 [2] => 610 [3] => 611" . Maybe it has something to do with timestamps? You come up in your function with $time, and then say given $time is a timestamp. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: To be clear: I want to save the times in an array that I can insert in a table (I think that's possible, right). I don't want to update the database records, but insert the new records seperately.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a row from the query result? What's the format of Time_D?

Comment: The type of Time_D in the database is time (not timestamp). You mean an example of the working query of the original records? The output of print_r($rows) is "Array ( [0] => 08:00:00 [1] => 09:00:00 [2] => 10:00:00"